# When using Angular 1.6 ng-switch displaying key and value in filter list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-controller

Im trying to create a conditional filter for a list of products, it was working fine until i changed the product model to allow for multiple categories. Once that happened the filter broke and this was displayed
[Broken Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VpVP.png)

This is an example of the json structure of the product

```
       {
        "title": "Product 2",
        "designer": "Designer 1",
        "id": "314",
        "category": [{
          "name": "Cat 5",
          "name": "Cat 3",

        }],
        "collection": "Collection 2",
        "type": "Type 2",
      },
```

And this is the controller for the filter

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, Products) {
$scope.data = Products;
$scope.filter = {};
$scope.categories = ['category','type','collection','designer'];

$scope.addProps = function(obj, array) {
  if (typeof array === 'undefined') {
    return false;
  }
  return array.reduce(function (prev, item) {
    if (typeof item[obj] === 'undefined') {
      return prev;
    }
    return prev + parseFloat(item[obj]);
  }, 0);
}

$scope.getItems = function (obj, array) {
  return (array || []).map(function (w) {
    return w[obj];
  }).filter(function (w, idx, arr) {
    if (typeof w === 'undefined') {
      return false;
    }
    return arr.indexOf(w) === idx;
  });
};
// matching with AND operator
$scope.filterByPropertiesMatchingAND = function (data) {
  var matchesAND = true;
  for (var obj in $scope.filter) {
    if( $scope.filter.hasOwnProperty(obj) ) {
      if (noSubFilter($scope.filter[obj])) continue;
      if (!$scope.filter[obj][data[obj]]) {
        matchesAND = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return matchesAND;
};
// matching with OR operator
$scope.filterByPropertiesMatchingOR = function (data) {
  var matchesOR = true;
  for (var obj in $scope.filter) {
    if( $scope.filter.hasOwnProperty(obj) ) {
      if (noSubFilter($scope.filter[obj])) continue;
      if (!$scope.filter[obj][data[obj]]) {
        matchesOR = false;
      } else {
       matchesOR = true;
        break;
      }
     }
   }
  return matchesOR;
 };
```

How do just access the values for the categories and then only display unique categories? Here is the link to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48qLjg2z/7/), I've tried to get this code working on js fiddle for the last 2 hours but to no avail.

### EDIT

Updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/48qLjg2z/7/
1. Lint the json file

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your fiddle. Try creating a new fiddle

I have created [new one](http://jsfiddle.net/48qLjg2z/) and it shows a different error (product not defined).

```
 var products = product_list
```

Note: I have used Angular 1.5

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it is the trailing comma, after `Cat 3`, here:

```
"category": [{
  "name": "Cat 5",
  "name": "Cat 3",

}],
```

"JavaScript has allowed trailing commas in array literals since the beginning...JSON, however, disallows trailing commas."

**Source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas

---

**EDIT:** Just as a resource, you can always validate JSON, here: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thank you i've  updated the fiddle with correct json

Comment: Are you having the same problem?